BMT question on Probability
Kait rolls a fair 6-sided die until she rolls a 6. if she rolls a 6 on the nth roll, she then rolls the die n more times. what is the probability that she rolls a 6 during these next $n$ times?
This can be treated as two events, event $A_n$ she rolls a 6 on the $n$th roll and event $B_n$ she rolls a 6 during the next $n$ times.
$P(A_n) = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{6}$
$P(B_n) = 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}$
Required Probability is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)\times P(B_n)=\\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{5^{n-1}}{6^n} -\frac{5^{2n-1}}{6^{2n}}\right],$$
which gives $\frac{6}{11}.$
Should be correct now!!

I would read the problem as requiring that she get at least one six in the second $n$ tosses.  Not exactly one.  And of course you need to compute a sum over the cases.

That is,  $n$ is not a specified parameter of the problem.  It was introduced to explain the rules... she tosses until she gets a $6$ and then tosses the same number of times over again.

Thanks lulu, would edit answer the question?

No. You still need to sum over $n$.

@lulu No need to sum, there is a simpler solution.

Thanks for the hints

@Aig, Lulu was attempting to correct my solution and indeed yours looks very elegant - Thanks both of you

@lulu Ok, I see. Sorry, I didn’t mean to be rude.

I just improved your answer. Note that the events $A_n$ and $B_n$ depend on $n$.

What is the meaning of "BMT" in the title?

@Aig. No worries

BMT stands for Berkeley Math Tournament!!

Let us call rolls before $6$ odd, and after $6$ even. Imagine Kait makes rolls in this order: an odd roll, then an even roll, an odd roll, and so on.
Let us find the probability $p$ that Kait will roll $6$ first on her odd roll: $$p=\frac16+\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot p.$$ Indeed, either Kait rolls $6$ right away, or she misses and she misses her second roll, and then it’s the starting position again. So, $$p=\frac6{11}.$$
Now let’s find the probability in question. It’s equal to $$\frac6{11}\cdot\frac16+\frac5{11}.$$
Indeed, either Kait rolls $6$ first on her odd roll (with probability $\frac6{11}$), then she must roll $6$ immediately after (with probability $\frac16$). Or she rolls $6$ first on her even roll, and then everything is set already.
So the answer is $$\frac6{11}.$$
